# Pytest mock an object returned via yield and check whether a method of that object is called

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, pytest-mock

I have a piece of code need to be tested via pytest

```
def my_function(value):
  with some_generator() as gen:
    gen.some_method(value)
```

I need to check whether the some_method has been called or not. I have used `pytest-mock` to mock the some_generator method to return a `MagicMock` and used that object to check if the method is called. But it is returning false. Also the return value I assigned is not reflected to the `some_method`

```
def test_myfunction(mocker):
    generator = mocker.patch('some_generator')
    mocked_obj = mock.MagicMock()
    generator.return_value = mocked_obj
    my_function(1)
    assert mocked_obj.some_method.called
```

The test is always failing even though the `gen.some_method(value)` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two problems:

1. You're not telling `mocker` where `some_generator` is. I think you need to include a module name.
2. You're mocking the return value of the generator, but not the `__enter__()` call that the [with statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) makes. You don't need a separate mock object for that, `mocker` already creates a mock object for `return_value` and any nested attributes.

Here's a fixed version of your test:

```
from scratch import my_function

def test_myfunction(mocker):
    generator = mocker.patch('scratch.some_generator')
    my_function(1)
    assert generator.return_value.__enter__.return_value.some_method.called
```

Just for completeness, here's the runnable version of `my_function` that I used:

```
# scratch.py

def some_generator():
    pass


def my_function(value):
  with some_generator() as gen:
    gen.some_method(value)
```